# in .profile file, why the PATH variable doesn't need to be exported?

Tags: 16.04

I'm pretty new to linux world and quite confused for the reason why in ubuntu's .profile file, the line defining the PATH variable doesn't need to be exported:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

I was expecting

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

thank you very much in advance for your feedback

PS: using xenial/16.04 version

Answer (score 0):

Because `$PATH` is already in your environment. Having `$PATH` in it makes it add it to the variable.

(Basically somewhere before your `.profile` is parsed `$PATH` was already exported).